# Can a JFrame reappear when a certain key combination is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The `defaultCloseOperation()` in my JFrame is set to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`. The IDE shows that the program is still running and there is no way to get the `JFrame` back.

I want to know, how do I get the `JFrame` to be visible again if a certain key combination is pressed like `SHIFT+V` ? Like in some parental control and surveillance softwares

I know `KeyListener` can not be used cause it needs something focussable to which input can be sent... so what is the way around ??
Can it reappear when some keys are pressed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- not directly and possible with Java, Swing GUI doesn't reacting to any Key or Mouse Events if isn't visible on the screen and hasn't Focus owner
- you can use [SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) as standard workaround, [there you can from JMenuItems Action to display your container again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968)

EDIT

- notice to the 1st. point, some of [Mouse Event are accesible and is possible to thare those events, valid for Win7/8 and for JButtons Components, JTableHeader...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548238/getrootpane-default-button-is-this-a-bug/15550077#15550077), but contianer must be visible on the screen

Comment: I was making a surveillance software so I need to have that facility. What other option apart from `SystemTray` do I  have ? JNA ??

Comment: yes will be possible, but is about KeyLogger, then probably can be antivirus sensitive, SystemTray is proper and direct way

Answer (score 1):

First of you make a windows adapter so that you can use the windowClosing method inside it.
This method overrides the default EXIT_ON_CLOSE or in you case DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE and write what you want to happen when the program tries to exit on the red X. Hope it helps