# JPanel KeyListener Not Working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, setfocus

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class AnaPencere{
    JFrame pen;
    AnaPencere(){
        pen = new JFrame("Ana Pencere");
        pen.setSize(613, 253);
        pen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pen.setResizable(false);
        pen.add(new Cizim());
        pen.setVisible(true);
    }


    private class Cizim extends JPanel{

        private Cizim() {
            this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the project, everything works as expected, but when I press a key, I am not seeing the expected result in the console

Comment: yes i press key but not work

Answer (score 7):

- add `setFocusable(true)` for `JPanel` with added `KeyListener`
- maybe there no reason to hunting for `Focus`, `setFocusable`, use `KeyBindings` instead
- there you can to [set programatically the focus in the components hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550077/714968)