# Switching JPanels with Enter key

Tags: java

I'm trying to program a game that has a title screen, and when you press Enter it advances to the game.  The issue that I'm running into is that you can't put add a `JPanel` from a `KeyPressed` method.

I have one panel for the title and another for the game board, what is likely the best way to go about this?

Comment: Take a look at  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599748/jpanel-keylistener-not-working

Comment: The code won't even compile with an add method in the KeyPressed method.  Making the panel focusable so it will register key presses isn't the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I have one panel for the title and another for the game board, what is likely the best way to go about this?

Use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) so you can easily switch from the title panel to the game panel.

Your title panel should also probably have a button like "Start Game" so the user knows what to do. Then they can either click the button or press Enter.

> and when you press Enter it advances to the game

To make the button the default button (so it responds to Enter) for the panel you can use:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(gameButton);
```

If you don't like the idea of adding a button then you will need to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at CardLayout.